# Using a websocket or APE(Ajax Push Engine) technology on a Webhost

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a question which I can't seem to answer after searching for an answer on google.
I have a website hosted on a web host, but I want to introduce some real-time functionality on it, like a real-time notification system, or maybe a chat system.

As I understand the short-polling and long-polling methods of simulating a live feature are kinda obsolete. Today with the modern HTML5, we can use Websockets as I understand, or APE(Ajax Push Engine).
The thing is that I don't understand, how do I use websocket or APE on the webhost if they require a server to which they connect in order to work ?

How can I run that server along with my website on the same host ? Or maybe I am missing something ?

Can you give me some information on this problem, that I can read?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is just another protocol. It works on port 80, so luckly you don't need a new server.

You just need to implement an abstraction level on your backend (but maybe it can do itself) that gets the HTTP request and looks if there are the `upgrade` headers.

If the answer is yes, go to websocket code, if not use standard HTTP.